# What is difference between ExpectedConditions.refresh and ExpectedConditions.stalenessof

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, expected-condition

Could you please help me to understand the `ExpectedConditions.refresh` and `ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf`.

Comment: Its not ExpectedConditions.refresh(). Its ExpectedConditions.refreshed().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ExpectedCondtion.referesh` accepts `ExpectedCondtion` as an argument.

Let's suppose you have a text field element which is manipulated by the application and it's redrawn. Normally, you would get `StaleElementReferenceException` because when `WebDriver` invokes `findElement` method, it saves the REFERENCE to the object. If the object is redrawn, there reference to the object is no longer actual and `StaleElementReferenceException` is thrown.

`ExpectedCondition.stalenessOf` waits until the element is redrawn. This might be helpful to wait if DOM manipulation has occured. Then, you can find your element again and perform the operation (or use element created by PageFactory instead of refinding it).

However, the element might be manipulated many times (for example via jQuery calls of the front-end). In this case, waiting until the element is stale, and trying to find it, might throw `StaleElementReferenceException` anyway, because the element got stale AGAIN.

In that case, you can use `ExpectedCondition.refresh(<my-expected-condition>)`. This will allow you to perform operations within the time frame, regardless of staleness of the element

Comment: ExpectedCondition.stalenessOf does not wait until the element is redrawn, it waits until the current reference of the element is detached from the DOM.  It may be redrawn after that has happened, but it also may not be redrawn.

Comment: I wrote that `StaleElementReferenceException` is thrown if the reference to the object is no longer actual. Redrawn of the object is just an example so OP can comprehend how this happens

Comment: @Fenio ExpectedCondition.stalenessOf() waits until element becomes stale i.e. deattached from DOM.It does  NOT wait until element is redrawn.

Comment: @aLearner read the comments above